# How can I get the csv file line content and save it to the database using NiFi processors?

Tags: apache-nifi

See example scenario:

csv file content

```
john|doe|1
stacy|doe|2
```

database fields

```
fname | lname | list_index | raw_text
```

My objective is to ingest and save CSV file content to database using nifi processor.  See sample output inserted in the database below including the record inserted in raw_text column.

```
 fname | lname | list_index | raw_text
  john | doe   |     1      | "john|doe|1 " 
 stacy | doe   |     2      | "stacy|doe|2"
```

Comment: What processors have you already checked?

Comment: You'll want ListFile -> FetchFile -> PutDatabaseRecord

Comment: Without a header on the file though, you'll likely want ReplaceText before PutDatabaseRecord to insert the header line so the CSVReader you create to use with PutDatabaseRecord will parse the fields correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do a lot of data customization then you can use `ExecuteScript` processor to do data manipulation, pipeline should be something like -

`ListFile -> FetchFile -> ExecuteScript -> PutDatabaseRecord`

Configure your `ExecuteScript` as below,

Script Engine: python

Script Body:

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.apache.nifi.processors.script import ExecuteScript
from org.python.core.util.FileUtil import wrap
from io import StringIO
import sys
import os
import datetime


class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):

        with wrap(inputStream) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            updated_lines = []
            header_line = 'fname|lname|list_index|raw_text' + '\n'
            updated_lines.append(header_line)
            for line in lines:
                updated_line = line.strip() + '|"' + line.strip() + '"' + '\n'
                updated_lines.append(updated_line)

            with wrap(outputStream, 'w') as filehandle:
                filehandle.writelines("%s" % line for line in updated_lines)

flow_file = session.get()

if flow_file:
    try:
        session.write(flow_file, PyStreamCallback())
        session.transfer(flow_file, ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)

    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        excp = str(exc_type) + str(fname)+ str(exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        attrMap = {'exception': str(excp)}
        flow_file = session.putAllAttributes(flow_file, attrMap)
        session.transfer(flow_file, ExecuteScript.REL_FAILURE)
```

Configure `PutDatabaseRecord` accordingly.